# Adding Regex matches to an array

Tags: arrays, regex, vb.net

I'm struggling to solve a small bit of code. What the code does is to first load a CSV file, line by line (starting by line 3), and add it to an array. Then run a regex match and I want to insert the value in an array.

This is my **working** code, it shows a msgbox with the actual matches:

```
Dim file = "C:\Users\David\Desktop\mycsv.csv"
    Dim basestatisticspath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file)
    Dim statistics() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file)
    'Dim x As Integer = statistics.Length
    'ReDim Preserve statistics(x)

    Dim regexlang As Regex = New Regex("(?<=^"")\[.*\]")
    Dim regexlinefilename As Regex = New Regex("(?<=^""\[.*?\]\s).*(?="")")
    Dim linefilename As Match = Nothing
    Dim langmatch As Match = Nothing
    Dim filename() As String
    Dim lang() As String

    For i = 2 To UBound(statistics)
        langmatch = regexlang.Match(statistics(i))
        linefilename = regexlinefilename.Match(statistics(i))
        MsgBox(langmatch.Value & linefilename.Value)
    Next
```

That works well and the actual matches is what I want. So my next step was to add each match to an array to then use it to generate other files.

Therefore I ended up with this:

```
    Dim file = "C:\Users\David\Desktop\myscv.csv"
    Dim basestatisticspath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file)
    Dim statistics() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file)
    'Dim x As Integer = statistics.Length
    'ReDim Preserve statistics(x)

    Dim regexlang As Regex = New Regex("(?<=^"")\[.*\]")
    Dim regexlinefilename As Regex = New Regex("(?<=^""\[.*?\]\s).*(?="")")
    Dim linefilename As Match = Nothing
    Dim langmatch As Match = Nothing
    Dim filename() As String
    Dim lang() As String

    ' Set all value line by line
    For i = 2 To UBound(statistics)
        langmatch = regexlang.Match(statistics(i))
        linefilename = regexlinefilename.Match(statistics(i))
        lang(i) = langmatch.Value.ToString
        filename(i) = linefilename.Value.ToString
        MsgBox(langmatch.Value & linefilename.Value)

    Next
```

After adding the below the program crashes on that line

```
    lang(i) = langmatch.Value.ToString
    filename(i) = linefilename.Value.ToString
```

I am assuming you can add the value of a regex match to a certain position of a string, but it seems I am wrong.

I´ve been searching for an answer with no results (at least to my poor understanding).

How could I convert each of the matches to a string and add it to the `i` position of the array?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** 
As @Tval explained, I solved it by including the size of the array when declaring it. Thanks!

```
    Dim filename(UBound(statistics)) As String
    Dim lang(UBound(statistics)) As String
```

Comment: Is it crashing or throwing an error? Have you assigned lang() and filename() a value or are they null?

Comment: @tval I get this: System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Both lang() and filename() are empty, just declared them on this form.

Comment: I would assume it's because you have not initialized the size of the array. Try this: Dim lang(UBound(statistics)) and Dim filename(UBound(statistics))

Comment: If it's throwing an exception, what's the error message?  As @tval said, unless you didn't share all of your code, the problem seems to be that you never set the length of the `lang` and `filename` arrays, so they are still `Nothing`.  Try changing it to `Dim filename(UBound(statistics)) As String` and `Dim lang(UBound(statistics)) As String` to preallocate them to the necessary length.

Comment: @tval, thank you very much! That fixed it and now it´s working as expected (I will update the initial questions for future reference). I actually tried your suggestion before posting here and it didn´t work, I guess I did something wrong...
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @StevenDoggart, that´s all the code, nothing else.

Comment: @StevenDoggart sorry I didn´t notice your reply. So just for my reference, I though you could declare arrays without limit and that would work, why in this case isn't working without putting the limit `UBound(statistics)`?

Comment: Arrays are a fixed-sequential collection and their size must always be initialized. I would note also that since you are starting your for loop at 2 that the first few elements in your array will be 'Nothing'

Comment: It's a bit confusing in VB, since the syntax of the language muddies it quite a bit, so I'm not surprised you're confused.  Arrays are reference types, so that means that array variables may either reference an allocated fixed length array or they may be null.  If you just say `Dim x() As String`, without a size specified, that's the equivalent of saying `string[] x = null` in C#.  It's just declaring a null array variable.  To allocate it, you need to either set it equal to some fixed list (e.g. `x = New { "1", "2" }`) or use `ReDim` to allocate an empty array of some fixed length.

Comment: For instance, `Dim x(4) As String` in VB is the same as `string[] x = new string[5]` in C#.  It not only declares the array variable, but also creates the array object, 5 long, and sets the variable to reference it.  Alternatively, you can do it later as a second step.  So, `Dim x() As String` followed by `ReDim x(4)` is the equivalent of the C# command `string[] x = null` followed by `x = new int[5]`.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Thanks, I will take that into account going forward.

Comment: @tval, correct, the first 1 elements are empty but I hope that´s not a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize the array before you can reference it or you'll get a null reference error, also you can't reference an index that doesn't exist yet or you'll get an index out of range exception.

right now your using an array with a fixed length, so if you want to add a value to it you'll have to re-declare it one index larger every time.

If you want an array of a variable length id suggest using a list, so you can just append values to it without any issues

```
Dim myList = New List(Of String)
For Each foo As String In bar
    myList.Add(bar)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @doom87er I will do it going forward and practice the same exercise with a list.